# invalid initializer for rand() when assigning to array

Tags: arrays, c, random

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    int n;
    for(int i= 0;i < 5; i++ ){
    //type arrayName[arraysize];
      int arrayName[5] = rand();
        printf("array[%d] = %d\n",i,arrayName[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I got an error about an invalid initializer for rand(); How do I add a random to the array and give it a range?

Answer (score 3):

remember you can't initialize an array with random variables like that you must fill item by item

```c
array[i] = rand();
```

you need to just change your place of define variables like this

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    int arrayName[5];
    int n;
    int i;
    for(i = 0;i < 5; i++ ){
        arrayName[i] = rand();
        printf("array[%d] = %d\n",i,arrayName[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and this is a function that fill an array with random numbers

```c
void generateFunction(int* arr, int len) {
    while (len-- > 0) {
        *arr++ = rand();
    }
}
```

or in simple way

```c
void generateFunction(int* arr, int len) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        arr[i] = rand();
    }
}
```

Comment: even simpler: `for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)` and drop `int i;` alltogether

Comment: i belleive in some C compilers for (int i ...) not support and give  you an error

Comment: Any sane C compiler understands that. But it's true, some C compilers  that are older than 20 years might not understand it.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing two things here:

1. You haven't declared the array you intend to use. Declare it like this:

```c
int arrayName[5];
```

2. `rand()` call doesn't return integer array, it just return one integer. So you would want to replace this:

```c
int arrayName[5] = rand();
```

with this:

```c
arrayName[i] = rand();
```